# How to make a program that counts letters and produces output statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I really don't know where to go from here regarding this program. Here's what I've tried to make:

```
# Purpose: This function takes an alphabetic string and prints out the number
# of times each letter(upper-or lower-case) is in the string
# Parameter: string - a string of only alphabetic characters
# Return: None

def letter_counter(string):
    counter = 0
    string = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    letter = [ ] # ?

    while counter <= len(string):
        for letter in string: 
            if i == string[counter]:
                counter += 1 
                return counter

    print("The letter", letter, "is in", string, count, "time(s)")
    # Do I use append here? For loops? etc.?
```

Here's what the output should look like:

```
count("bAseBalls")
Letter b is in bAseBalls 2 time(s)
Letter a is in bAseBalls 2 time(s) 
Letter s is in bAseBalls 2 time(s)
Letter e is in bAseBalls 1 time(s)
Letter l is in bAseBalls 2 time(s)
```

Do I just use a lot of 'if' statements for printing out the number of times each letter appears in the string? Would you recommend 'while' vs 'for' loops in this program? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are overwriting the parameter `string` with a list of letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking it. All you need to do is split the string into lowercase letters and then use `collections.Counter` to count how many times each letter appears in the list.

```
#Imports counter to count items.
from collections import Counter

#Defines letter counter which takes string as an argument.
def letter_count(string):
    #Creates a copy of the string in lower case.
    lower_string = string.lower()
    #Uses list to make a list of letters in the string, and then uses counter to count how many letters are in the list.
    letters = Counter(list(lower_string))
    #Loops through the list of (element, count pairs).
    for letter in letters.items():
        #Prints the string with the element and the count.
        print("Letter", letter[0], "is in", string, letter[1], "time(s)")

letter_count("BaseBalLs")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel to count characters within a string. python can iterate over a string just as if it was a list. And even better: python has its own ascii letters: `string.ascii_lowercase`

dict comprehensions also can help you a lot here to keep your code simple and pythonic:

```
import string

def count_letters(word):
    l_word = word.lower()
    counts = { c: l_word.count(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase if l_word.count(c) > 0 }
    for char, count in counts.items():
        print("The letter {} is in {} {} time(s)".format(char, word, count))


count_letters('bAseBall')
```

output:

```
The letter a is in bAseBall 2 time(s)
The letter s is in bAseBall 1 time(s)
The letter b is in bAseBall 2 time(s)
The letter e is in bAseBall 1 time(s)
The letter l is in bAseBall 2 time(s)
```